# How do I use $wp_query->current_post with get_template_part? I'm trying to add post classes (first/last/even/odd) to custom loops

Tags: wp-query, post-class

... but $wp_query->current_post and the like don't work when I use get_template_part to pull in content.php files as modeled [by themes like twentynineteen](https://github.com/WordPress/twentynineteen/blob/master/template-parts/content/content.php). The variables don't carry over I guess?

Is there a way to add custom post classes to posts created by a custom query while also using get_template_part? Thank You.

Comment: what is the code of your custom loop?

Comment: If it's the main query, then you should be able to access the global `$wp_query` variable from a template part; for example, the `content.php` file linked from your question - `$wp_query->current_post` does work. And you could use the `post_class` [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) to add custom post classes.